# A different viewpoint of Hilbert's Theorem 90

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be a galois extension with galois group $G$($|G| = n$) cyclic and generated by $\sigma$. Let $\beta \in L$ have $N(\beta) = 1$. $N(.)$ is the norm function from $L$ to $K$.

Hilbert's theorem 90 states that there exists $x \in L$ such that $\sigma(x) = \beta x$. We can view $\sigma$ has a linear function of $L$ as a vector space over $K$ and then to prove the theorem we need to show that $\beta$ is an eigenvalue of $\sigma$.

Can we show this directly? I know of a related proof where we view $\sigma(x)/\beta$ as the linear function and show that $1$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: I don't think you can conclude that $\beta$ is an eigenvalue. After all there are (often) infinitely many elements of norm one, but at most $n$ eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes,  I realized that but I am not sure why it is not an eigenvalue in  the formulation I have set up @jyrki

Comment: Initially $\sigma$ is only linear over $K$. We can think of it having eigenvalues in an extension field $M$ of $K$. To realize the eigenvectors belonging to such an eigenvalue we would need to extend the scalars from $K$ to $M$ (just like when extending scalars from the reals to complex numbers) . That way we arrive at an $M$-linear extension of $\sigma: M\otimes_KL\to M\otimes_KL$. If we select $M=L$ here, the eigenvalues of $\sigma$ from $L$ will act on the former tensor factor, but $\beta$ will act on the latter. The two actions are not the same.

Comment: BTW I don't know a good answer to that. Just started thinking about it.. I have encountered the question myself when working on some problem, but I haven't seen this spelled out anywhere. Probably a better explanation is out there.

Comment: I think I need a bit more familiarity with tensors to understand what's going on here. I am working on it, hopefully I will understand it soon!

Comment: For example. 1) Think about the real rotation of the complex plane (viewed as a 2D-space over $\Bbb{R}$). That linear transformation actually is linear over $\Bbb{C}$, and viewed as a $\Bbb{C}$-linear mapping it has only a single eigenvalue, $e^{i\theta}$. But viewed as an $\Bbb{R}$-linear transformation it has two eigenvalues, $e^{\pm i\theta}$. 2) Take your $\sigma$. It satisfies the relation $\sigma^n=id$, so its eigenvalues are $n$th roots of unity.

Comment: I guess the simplest way to look at it is the following. Multiplication by $\beta$ is just another $K$-linear mapping $\mu_\beta:L \to L$. But $\mu_\beta$ does not commute with $\sigma$, so we should not expect that eigenspaces of $\sigma$ would be stable under $\mu_\beta$.

Comment: Yes, I think I get it. It helped me to play around with a quadratic field - thanks for your help!